# trying to create function which returns and displays a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to display output in terms of `keys: values` as:

```
dad:bob
Mom:lisa
brother : joe
& so on
```

But only values are shown in the output.

what changes should I make in this code to get the desired output?

```
d = dict(Dad='Bob', Mom='Lisa', Brother= 'joe')
def f2(Dad,Mom,Brother):
    print Dad,Mom,Brother
f2(**d)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23037395/2823755

Answer (score 5):

Use `**kwargs` for handling function keyword arguments:

```
d = dict(Dad='Bob', Mom='Lisa', Brother= 'joe')
def f2(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        print '%s:%s' % (key, value)
f2(**d)
```

prints:

```
Dad:Bob
Brother:joe
Mom:Lisa
```

Also see:

- [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)
- [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)